# Inserting new character into a formula at a particular position (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So let's say I have a formula "**=A1/5**" and I want to change it to "**=A1/sqrt(5**" i.e. inserting something at the second last position.

(subsequently I can do a simple **= cell&")"** to complete the formula).

I managed to do it but I took a very lengthy route, so wonder if anyone has idea how to quickly accomplish this.

My approach now:

1. Deformularize by replacing "=" with "" aka nothing.
2. Extracting the left part and rightmost part of the string separately by =LEFT(cell,LEN(cell)-1) and =RIGHT(cell,1)
3. For the rightmost part extracted (which is a single digit number), I simply do a ="sqrt("&cell
4. I then concatenate together a "=", the extracted left part and the amended right part.

this works, but as you can see, it took quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

This tiny macro will do the work for you:

```
Sub formulaFixer()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveCell.Formula
    arr = Split(s, "/")
    ActiveCell.Formula = arr(0) & "/SQRT(" & arr(1) & ")"
End Sub
```

It will convert:

```
=A1/5
```

into:

```
=A1/SQRT(5)
```

In fact, it can convert `=something/something else` into `=something/SQRT(something else)`

We can loop it over several cells, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out!